Beelink SEI8 running 20.04 I see no wifi in the GUI.....stock install
So like I said I'm connected to my wifi however there is no wifi in the preferences or in the pulldown on the top edge of the window.
I see the wifi I'm connected to in my /etc/netplan files.

03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)

OS INFO
 No LSB modules are available.
 Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
 Description:   Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
 Release:   20.04
Codename:   focal

netplan files

-rw-r--r--   1 root root   117 Sep  6  2021 00-installer-config.yaml

# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  wifis:
    wlp3s0:
      access-points:
        n_******0:
          password: *****
      dhcp4: true


-rw-------   1 root root   191 Sep  6  2021 00-installer-config-wifi.yaml

network:
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2

and this shows nothing in terms of wifi's in my house but when I run
nmcli device wifi list
IN-USE  BSSID  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 

I appreciate that but it is on a closed network VLAN behind a firewall away from the interent...
any actual advice on the issue?

The point release string comes from the base-files package.  That package is not published as a security update.  So this does NOT indicate that security updates have not been applied.

"I see the wifi I'm connected to in my /etc/netplan files." You don't actually show this. Please edit your question to show the contents of the netplan config files.

@slangasek and again what does this have to do with the lack of being able to see the Wifi in the GUI when I'm obviously connected to it....

@slangasek updated... with netplan files...

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and edit to include results from the wireless script, you could press y when asked to upload and just post the URL
